# Ajax Auto Refresh in Codeigniter causes browser to hang/crash

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter project where data is fetched from the database and shown in a tabular form in a view inside a div. The div is auto refreshed using ajax every 5 seconds.

The problem I am facing is after about 2-5 minutes, the browser starts to lag, and hangs. I have to then force quit my browser, clean up my memory to bring the system back to normal.

My Controller code

```
function view_data()
{
  $this->load->model('site');
  $data['list'] = $this->site->get_data()
  $this->load->view('data',$data);
}
```

Model Code

```
function get_data()
{
 $query = $this->db->get('data');
 return $query->result_array();
}
```

View Code

```
<script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
 $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$('#loaddiv').empty().load(window.location.href);
}, 1000);
</script>

<body>
<div id="loaddiv"><table>.....DATA...</table></div>
```

Comment: maybe the memory use by the browser is too damn high, have you tried it on other computers? what is you browser by the way? try getting a small amout of data first, and if it is successful try again with bigger data. until you know the cause of the problem if it is memory leak or the data ajax is fetching

Comment: I've tried it on Safari, Firefox on Mac